# Check box in grid view cause error for delete button (Web form c#)

Tags: c#, html, gridview

I have a grid view in a web application using C# that get data from a list. I want to delete a selected row of the grid view. I tried lots of codes but I get error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in line of "if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkAll")).Checked)" and "if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkBox")).Checked)". I would be thankful if anyone can help me and let me know what is the problem. Thank you so much.

```
My Html Code:
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="ProductID"
                         AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="False"  CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
                         HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" ShowFooter="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging"
                        PageSize="10"  OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBound" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <HeaderTemplate>
                                     <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
                                 </HeaderTemplate>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="Product ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price" HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Quantity" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" HeaderText="Total Price" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TotalPrice" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" /> 
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#bd62dd" BorderStyle="Double" BorderColor="#49093c" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"/>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#bd62dd" BorderStyle="Outset" BorderColor="#49093c" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>

My back code:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridView();
        }
    }



    private void BindGridView()
    {

List<CartItem> item = new List<CartItem>();
        item = Session["listOfOrder"] as List<CartItem>;
        int count = 0;
        bool English = true;

        if(item != null)
        {
            int Total = 0;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProductName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProductID", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UnitPrice", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("TotalPrice", typeof(string)));

            foreach (var items in item)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["ProductName"] = items.Name;
                dr["ProductID"] = items.Id;
                dr["UnitPrice"] = items.UnitPrice;
                dr["Quantity"] = items.Quantity;
                dr["TotalPrice"] = items.ItemTotal;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                Total += Total + items.ItemTotal;
                count++;
            }
            ViewState["datatable"] = dt;
            GridViewProducts.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewProducts.DataBind();

                GridViewProducts.FooterRow.Cells[4].Text = "Total";
                GridViewProducts.FooterRow.Cells[4].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                GridViewProducts.FooterRow.Cells[5].Text = Total;


            lblDeleteResults.Visible = true;
            lblDeleteResults.Text = "List is empty.";
            lblDeleteResults.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CartItem> item = Session["listOfOrder"] as List<CartItem>;
        int Count = 1;
        BindGridView();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewProducts.Rows)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkAll")).Checked)
            {
                item = null;
            }
            if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkBox")).Checked)
            {
                item.Remove(item[Count]);
                Count++;
            }
        }
        Session["listOfOrder"] = item;
        BindGridView();    
    }
```

Comment: Did not see where you got your row

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. Sorry it seems it was deleted and I did not notice that. I have added the code. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: I would be thankful if any one could answer me. I am in urgent. I appreciate your help friends. Thank you so much.